# how to use sessions in my project to store project id and how to match sessions in code

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

i want to store selected project's project_id in session and check it for the current user who are logged in... and match it in _shared.html.erb file.

how can i write condition in _shared file and how can i match them in controller??\

i am selecting project from dropdown list.

Jquery is needed to do... i got id of selected project in dropdown list but not able to list activity...

```
@project = Project.find(params[:id])    
session[:project_id] = @project.id
```

is this works to store session?

i want to list all activity acording to project select from dropdown list and make session until i select next project.

all activity should change for the project to my dashboard. and same for other links that also works for it.

if you have any best and understandable ajax video or tutorial link then pls suggest to me....

thanks in advance.. :)

Answer (score 1):

This is the way u can store in sessions.

```
 @project = Project.find(params[:id])    
 session[:project_id] = @project.id
```

you are going in right direction. and access this session using

```
 session[:project_id]
```

where u needed.